# cookie authentication in angular with different server

Tags: angular, cookies

I'm writing an angular app using forms authentication to interface a remote web api using cookies.
I created the http interceptor that clones the request and add
request = request.clone({
withCredentials: true
});

It's working fine if the app and web api runs in the same server, but if the server is different, the login is ok, but seems the sessions cookie is not saved and not reused in the API calls.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Cookies are only exchanged with the domain they were set with. So you probably need a different mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem is the type of http connection, and is related to the SameSite cookie management.
To make it work you have to use a secure/HTTPS connection, doesn't work with plain HTTP connections.